How do I generate an array of full objects from partial objects using typescript
It's for writing unit tests. Say I have this:
type X = 1 | 2 | 3;
type Y = 4 | 5 | 6;
type Obj = {
  x: X;
  y: Y;
};

I want to do something like this:
const getObjTemplate = (overrideProperties: Partial<Obj>): Obj => ({
  x: 1,
  y: 4,
  ...overrideProperties,
});

describe('Test suite', () => {
  const objs: Obj[] = [
    { x: 1 },
    { x: 2 },
    { x: 2 },
    { x: 3 },
  ].map(getObjTemplate);

  test('...', () => {
    // ...
  });
});

I get told that Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'X | undefined'. referring to property x, because apparently it's incompatible with the Partial<Obj>. Perhaps I'm abusing Partial or making too many assumptions about what Typescript will work out for itself, but I would have assumed it could work out the type of x and that extending with property x should fit the same type.
How do I tell the function that any overriding properties should be of the same types?
Typescript playground here.

([...] as const).map would be one way to retain narrower types. Or start by defining a Partial<Obj>[] explicitly. Otherwise your pre-map array is just { x: number }[].

• Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] without typos like getTemplate. • The prev comment is correct, you probably want a const assertion or the like. If that meets your needs, someone can answer the question or find a suitable duplicate. If not, what's missing?

You haven't clarified the type of [{ x: 1 }, { x: 2 }, { x: 2 }, { x: 3 }, ]. Typescript infers it as {x: number}[], whereas you want it to be inferred as Partial<Obj>[].
You can declare an object
const partials: Partial<Obj>[] = [{ x: 1 }, { x: 2 }, { x: 2 }, { x: 3 }, ]
const objs: Obj[] = partials.map(getObjTemplate)

You can assert the literal is readonly
const objs: Obj[] = ([{ x: 1 }, { x: 2 }, { x: 2 }, { x: 3 }, ] as const).map(getObjTemplate)


TypeScript is having problems with this because is not understanding that { x: 1 } is not Obj but Partial<Obj>:
const objs: Obj[] = [
    { x: 1 },
    { x: 2 },
    { x: 2 },
    { x: 3 },
  ].map(getObjTemplate);

You can fix the problem by breaking it into two steps:
const testPartialObjs: Partial<Obj>[] = [
  { x: 1, },
  { x: 2 },
  { x: 2 },
  { x: 3 },
];

const testObjs: Obj[] = testPartialObjs.map(getObjTemplate);


as Partial<Obj> can hide type issues

Removed the casting option; while it is true that casting with as should be avoided in this particular case, it was acceptable.
